# Correct API call to request JSON-formatted data from Imgur?

Tags: python, json, api, imgur

I am having a bit of trouble understanding API calls and the URLs I'm supposed to use for grabbing data from Imgur. I'm using the following URL to grab JSON data, but I'm receiving old data: `http://imgur.com/r/wallpapers/top/day.json`

But if I strip the `.json` from the end of the URL, I see the top pictures from today.

All I want is the JSON data from the top posts of today from Imgur, but keep getting data the refers to Dec 18th, 2014.

I'm using the call in a Python script. I have a token from Imgur to do the stuff, and reading the API documentation, I see a lot of the examples start with `https://api.` instead of `http://imgur.`

Which one should I use?

Comment: Well `https` is more secure so if imgur have mentioned `https` in their documentation than you should go for that. And can you include your code of how you are calling your API and link to the API documentation too.

Comment: Post the link to where this endpoint is documented.

Comment: Actually, it seems like the endpoint is working properly now. When I first tried it out I was getting 12-18 also, but now I'm getting 01-01.

Comment: it's probably due to **cache control**, you can set **no-cache** headers and send along with your requests

Comment: @mattm could you explain what you did?

Comment: copy and pasted the url you posted into a web browser

Comment: Oh I see. Are you now getting data from 01-01?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imgur updated their docs, so the new and correct form of the URL I used was:

`r = requests.get("https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/r/earthporn/top/")`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to **cache control**, you can set it to **no-cache** with your headers and send along with your requests.

Sample (I'm using **requests**):

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://imgur.com/r/wallpapers/top/day.json', 
                 headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
# ... your stuff here ...
```